# what is the best algorithm to cluster this data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

[image]

can some one help me find a good clustering algorithm that will cluster this into 3 clusters without defining the number of clusters.

i have tried many algorithms in its basic form.. nothing seems to work properly.

```
clustering = AgglomerativeClustering().fit(temp)
```

same way i tried the dbscan and kmeans too.. just used the guidelines from sklean. i couldn't get the expected results.

my original data set is a 1D list of numbers.. but the order of the numbers matters, so generated a 2D list as bellow.

```
temp = []
for i in range(len(avgs)):
    temp.append([avgs[i], i+1])
clustering = AgglomerativeClustering().fit(temp)
```

in plotting piloting i used a similter range as the y axis

```
ax2.scatter(range(len(plots[i])), plots[i], c=np.random.rand(3,))
```

the order of the data matters, so this need to clustered into 3. and there might be some other data sets that the data is very good so that the result of that need to be just one cluster.

[Link to the list if someone want to try](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10JnlRmateZA7EndCEsQwXiq31hyL2N9g)

so i tried using the step detection and got the following image according to ur answer. but how can i find the values of the peaks.. if i get the max value i can get one of them.. but how to get the rest of it.. the second max is not an answer because the one right next to the max is the second max

[image]

Comment: why are you trying to close without even a comment??

Comment: The question is how you want to cluster your data. You plot your data as 2D and say you want 3 clusters. On the other hand you say that your data is intrinsically only one-dimensional and the second dimension does not have any meaning. So do you want to cluster your data in 1D or 2D? It seems like 2D but it also seems that this doesn't make sense since your data is only 1D and the apparent cluster structure on the plot only comes from the fact that you added `x = range(len(data))`. You could've also done `x = np.zeros(len(data))` and the situation would be much different.

Comment: well you can consider the data as 2D then, the range(len(data)) will generate the order of the data and that matters.. so will edit the question now

Comment: @a_guest any problem now?

Comment: i didnt just plot it like this because it need two axis.. this data is time rated, so the order of the data means something.. thats why i need to cluster into 3

Comment: Clustering in 2D is not the right approach here. You have a time series that you want to segment. Have a look at step detection.

Comment: @ypnos thanks for the point.. i have been looking into it and there are no packages made for this right.. and i coldnt find a method suitable for this.. specially because i don't know how many steps are there.. if would be a great help if you could provide an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is **not 2d coordinates**. So don't choose an algorithm designed for that!

Instead your data appears to be sequential or time series.

What you want to use is a **change point detection** algorithm, capable of detecting a change in the mean value of a series.

A simple approach would be to compute the sum of the next 10 points minus the sum of the previous 10 points, then look for extreme values of this curve.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. i did managed to calculate what u said and plot.. but i can't seem to figure out how i can find the two (can be any number) peaks. of that plot

Comment: Local maximum (no larger value nearby) and larger than 100?

Comment: i my data.. its way more complicated than that.. but i think for now i have managed something.. thanks